# Django - Site requested, but not rendered

Tags: django

I tied to create something with Django, but I currently suffer from a problem with the return statement. It doesn't work.
Here is my code:

`
def acc_settings(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":

    # Extract JSON dictionary from request
    dict = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))

    if dict["request"] == "user_data_change":
        request.user.first_name = dict["firstname"]
        request.user.last_name = dict["lastname"]
        request.user.username = dict["email"]
        request.user.email = dict["email"]
        request.user.save()

        return redirect("/")

    if dict["request"] == "delete_account":
        print("Account deletion requested!")

        try:
            # Delete all models assigned to this user
            bgmodel = dashModels.diabetesData.objects.filter(user=helpers.key)
            profilemodel = models.userProfile.objects.filter(user=helpers.key)
            usermodel = User.objects.get(username = request.user.email)
            bgmodel.delete()
            profilemodel.delete()
            logout(request)
            usermodel.delete()
            return redirect("/")
            
        except:
            return redirect("/")
        
    if dict["request"] == "renew_keyfile":
        print("Keyfile will be renewed!")

        # Generate a new private key for the user
        key = pgpy.PGPKey.new(PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncryptOrSign, 4096)
        uid = pgpy.PGPUID.new('{} {}'.format(request.user.first_name, request.user.last_name), email=request.user.email)

        key.add_uid(uid, usage={KeyFlags.Sign},
                        hashes=[HashAlgorithm.SHA256],
                        ciphers=[SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.AES256],
                        compression=[CompressionAlgorithm.Uncompressed],
                    )
            
        profilemodel = models.userProfile.objects.get(user=helpers.key)
        bgmodel = dashModels.diabetesData.objects.get(user=helpers.key)
        bgmodel.user = key
        profilemodel.user = key
        bgmodel.save()
        profilemodel.save()

        response = HttpResponse(key, content_type='multipart/signed')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="new_key.asc"'

        logout(request)
        return response
    


context = {
    "hostname": helpers.hostname,
    "firstname": request.user.first_name,
    "lastname": request.user.last_name,
    "email": request.user.email,
}
            
template = TemplateResponse(request, "settings.html", context)
return template.render()`
```

So, the 'return redirect("/")' does work, in the console I can see the request for my index site. But the index site is not rendered!

Do you have any ideas why it does so?

I checked my views and the urls.py file. Everything correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "return redirect("/")" with "return redirect(index)", or replace "index" with the name of the function that renders your index page

Comment: Does that also work if the index wiew is in another views file?

Comment: you will have to import the reference to the file like "from .relative_path_to_other_view_file import *"